# Force composer to use specific branch

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have the following requirements in my composer json

- A dev-feature1
- B dev-develop

Requirement B requires also A but on dev-develop

When I use composer update it will errored because requirement cant be solved. Can I force composer to use my requirement?

I need it for easier testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer allows to create [inline aliases](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias).

So your require package definition should look like this

```
"require": {
    "acme/A": "dev-feature as dev-develop"
}
```